# Git list branches merged into a branch but not into another

Tags: git, version-control

Here is a example graph of branch/commit history:

```
A---  master
|\
| B-----G--------P feature2
|\       \        \
| -----F--J--L--O--Q integration
|\    /     /  /
| C--E--H--K  /    feature1
 \           /
  D---------M feature3
```

In a normal circumstances, we merge integration branch into master and done. 
But... there are exceptional cases where only some specific feature must be merged into master... ex: only feature1. 
In that case, feature1 branch is merged into master (commit R):

```
A-------------------------R   master
|\                       /
| B-----G--------P      /     feature2
|\       \        \    /
| -----F--J--L--O--Q  /       integration
|\    /     /  /     /
| C--E--H--K--/------         feature1
 \           /
  D---------M                 feature3
```

Question: I would like a command that would tell me which branches are merged in integration but not in master. Result should be: feature2 and feature3.

Is a cross-reference between these 2 commands the only way ?

```
git branch --no-merged master
git branch --merged integration
```

Or, it could be also a command that list merge commits in integration branch not present in master. Result should be: J,O,Q

Comment: Well done on the ASCII art!

Answer (score 20):

```
 comm -12 <(sort <(git branch --no-merged master)) <(sort <(git branch --merged integration))
```

Comment: Well it seems the current version of msysgit does not support process substitution... Moreover, the fc command in git bash seems to be the unix one, not the windows one.

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin Try `which fc` to see which `fc` command is being used. If this is not the one you want, you can type the full path to run the "correct" `fc` command.

Comment: Just one quick addition - "comm" apparently needs the inputs to be sorted, so this should give the correct results:

`comm -12 <(sort <(git branch --no-merged master)) <(sort <(git branch --merged integration))`

Comment: We're seeing that this gives fairly inconsistent results between developers. We're able to mitigate this a little bit using the `-r` on both branch commands, and running against remotes origin/master and origin/integration: `comm -12 <(sort <(git branch -r --no-merged origin/master)) <(sort <(git branch -r --merged origin/integration))`